# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed even though the connection is open

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, connection

I have encountered this "Invalid attempt to call Read when the reader is closed." error and I have tried to solve it for so many times. I think the connection is open but it still shows this error. Can somebody tell me why?
Here is the code:

```
 Dim ConnComName As String
 Dim sqlConnComName As SqlConnection
 Dim sqlCmdComName As SqlCommand
 Dim sqlComName As String

 ConnComName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString
 sqlComName = "Select COUNT(*) from TicketDetails where Company = '" & Company.SelectedValue & "' AND Priority = '" & Priority.SelectedValue & "' AND Application = '" & Application.SelectedValue & "' AND Creator = '" & Creator.Text & "' AND Status = '" & Status.SelectedValue & "' AND Module = '" & [Module].SelectedValue & "' AND Category = '" & Category.SelectedValue & "' AND IssueType = '" & IssueType.SelectedValue & "' AND IssueDescription = '" & IssueDescription.Text & "' "
 sqlConnComName = New SqlConnection(ConnComName)
 sqlConnComName.Open()
 sqlCmdComName = New SqlCommand(sqlComName, sqlConnComName)

 Dim sqlReader_ComName As SqlDataReader = sqlCmdComName.ExecuteReader()

 While sqlReader_ComName.Read()
     If sqlReader_ComName.GetValue(0) < 1 Then

     ElseIf sqlReader_ComName.GetValue(0) > 0 Then
         
         Dim CompanyName As String

         Dim ConnComName01 As String
         Dim sqlConnComName01 As SqlConnection
         Dim sqlCmdComName01 As SqlCommand
         Dim sqlComName01 As String

         ConnComName01 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString
         sqlComName01 = "Select Company from TicketDetails Where Company = '" & Company.SelectedValue & "' AND Priority = '" & Priority.SelectedValue & "' AND Application = '" & Application.SelectedValue & "' AND Creator = '" & Creator.Text & "' AND Status = '" & Status.SelectedValue & "' AND Module = '" & [Module].SelectedValue & "' AND Category = '" & Category.SelectedValue & "' AND IssueType = '" & IssueType.SelectedValue & "' AND IssueDescription = '" & IssueDescription.Text & "' "
         sqlConnComName01 = New SqlConnection(ConnComName01)
         sqlConnComName01.Open()
         sqlCmdComName01 = New SqlCommand(sqlComName01, sqlConnComName01)
         Dim sqlReader_ComName01 As SqlDataReader = sqlCmdComName01.ExecuteReader()

         While sqlReader_ComName01.Read()

             CompanyName = sqlReader_ComName01.GetValue(0)
      ' end while ComName01
         End While
         sqlReader_ComName01.Close()
         sqlCmdComName01.Dispose()
         sqlConnComName.Close()

     End If

 End While

 sqlReader_ComName.Close()
 sqlCmdComName.Dispose()
 sqlConnComName.Close()
```

Comment: Except the connection isn't open because you close it after the inner `While` loop. This is a perfect example of why you should use `Using` statements to create objects like that connection. In that case, you can't forget to dispose or dispose in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments, the reason you are getting the error is because you are using a shared SqlConnection, which you close at the end of your inner loop, although there is actually no good reason to share a connection object here; `.NET` uses connection pooling behind the scenes, so there is little or no downside to creating new connection objects for every command, and it can often save confusion like this. You should also use `Using` blocks to ensure that all your managed resources are disposed of correctly and at the right time. Finally, and I can't stress this enough, **[use Parameterised queries](https://bobby-tables.com/)**, your code is vulnerable to injection, malformed SQL, type errors and will be unable to make use of query plan caching.

Although you have two loops in your code, all you ever do in those loops is to assign a value to a string:

```
 While sqlReader_ComName01.Read()

     CompanyName = sqlReader_ComName01.GetValue(0)
 End While
```

So with every inner and outer loop, you overwrite the previous value, making all loops other than the last completely pointless. Since your SQL has no order by, you also have no idea which order the results will come in, so the "last" record could be any record here.

You don't need two loops here, if you only want a single value from the database, just select single value, there is no point returning 500 records if you are only going to use one.

So with all these changes your code might look something like this (forgive any syntax errors, it is about 8 years since I last wrote any VB.net)

```
Dim CompanyName As String
'Change SQL to only select 1 record, use an order by, and use parameters
Dim sql As String = "Select TOP (1) Company from TicketDetails Where Company = @Company AND Priority = @Prioirty AND Application = @Application AND Creator = @Creator AND Status = @Status AND Module = @Module AND Category = @Category AND IssueType = @IssueType AND IssueDescription = @IssueDescription ORDER BY Company"

' Create new conneciton in Using block
Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnString").ConnectionString)
    'Create new command in using block
    Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        
        'Add parameters to command, change your data types and lengths as necessary
        command.Parameters.Add("@Company", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Company.SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@Priority", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Priority.SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@Application", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Application.SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@Creator", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Creator.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Status.SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@Module", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = [Module ].SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Category.SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@IssueType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = IssueType.SelectedValue
        command.Parameters.Add("@IssueDescription", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = IssueDescription.Text
        
        'Open the connection
        connection.Open()

        'Create the data reader
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        
            'If the reader.Read() method returns true, then there is a record, so read it and assign it to the variable
            If reader.Read()
                CompanyName = reader.GetString(0);
            End If
        End Using
    
    End Using
End Using
```